# Need for Speed 2012 Alternate Keyboard Controls

Tags: keyboard, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

How to change the alternate controls in Need for Speed: Most Wanted 2012 ?

for example I want to make the WASD (accelerate - steer left - brake - steer right) and in the same time I want to use the arrow keys ?